# Compare two column from different sheet and return numeric value on third

Tags: excel

I want to compare sheet 2 column "A" with sheet 1 column "A" (which contains text value ex:name). If do match return 1, if not return 2 on sheet 2 column "B".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below function in sheet2: column B

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=A1, 1, 2)
=IF(Sheet1!A2=A2, 1, 2)
.
.
```

You should get desired output. See screen-shots as asked :

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Outcome]

Comment: @mirza-sakibul-hoque You can automate the same using macros

Comment: Is there any way that I can write/use a formula in B1 and apply it to all the cells in column B?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am a newbie. Would you please share me the macro and how could I apply that on my excel file.

Comment: Without macro just follow Rajesh's instructions for cell B1 in sheet 2, then with your focus on that cell, cntl-shift-enter will highlight the column and then cntl-D will fill the formula down to the end of the column.

Comment: @mirza-sakibul-hoque : can you vote/mark as solution?

Comment: Actuallu I am new here. Can you tell me how should I vote for your answer?

Comment: Accept answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer 
Vote : http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Ok I did it. Thanks again.