# Compare two columns from two sheets contains different names of peoples and return numeric value on third

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, multiple-columns, vba

I want to compare "Sheet 2" "Column A" (which contains the name of 300 people) with "Sheet 1" "Column A" (which contains the name of 28 people).

Now I want write down a formula on "Sheet 2" "Column B" to see whether those 28 people (Sheet 1, Column A) do match/available/exist with/in/among the 300 people (Sheet 2, Column A). If do match return 2, if not return 8 on "Sheet 2" "Column B".

I am a newbie. So I hope I will learn a lot of things from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: these are really basics, look for `VLOOKUP`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare two column from different sheet and return numeric value on third](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090501/compare-two-column-from-different-sheet-and-return-numeric-value-on-third)

Comment: #Erik, that was little bit different. And as I am newbie, so it can happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$28,1,FALSE)),8,2)
```

Put it in cell **B1** in `Sheet2` and copy and fill down.